# Any example code that will only compile with a 64Bit JDK

Tags: java, 64-bit, 32-bit

Is there any Java code construct that will only compile if you are using a 64Bit JDK or in the Java world is this possible?

Comment: I don't think that is possible in JAVA as the bytecode generated for the code will be same for 64 and 32 bit machines.

Comment: Cheers,  that was what going to be my next question.  What I have done is compile my project using a 64 bit JDK, but I deployed it on a 32 bit JVM by mistake but it still worked.  Is this what you would expect? Why have 32 & 64 bit JDKs if there is no difference between the byte code generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not at the compilation level. Java compiler has no idea what kind of JVM it is going to run in and there is nothing JVM-specific in the .class files. The only difference you may experience is at runtime, but once again, no Java construct can discern it. You can read the architecture system property, but I'm quite sure that is not what you are aiming for.

As for your "next question" in the comment, a JDK contributes the full Java stack, including source code, compiled bytecode, and the JVM. The difference between a 32-bit and 64-bit JDK is, you're guessing already, in the JVM part.

Comment: Cheers lad,  the fog is starting to clear.  So,  in my 64 bit JDK, it's only the JRE that will be different?  I am developing on a 64 bit PC but this has no bearing on whither I use a 64 bit JDK for my development.  Just that when I want to run my code it will expect a 64 bit JVM installed on my pc? Do I have this correct?  thnx

Comment: Actually, not even that. The only kind of target you compile against is Java version, without any details of the underlying platform. Any JAR for Java 7 works with any Java 7 JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Java is specifically designed to shield the users of it from things such as the word length of the platform, whether 32bit or 64bit. Generally, it is impossible to construct anything in the language that is sensitive to this.

Therefore all code written in Java should compile on any platform.

Additionally, the compilers should be able to run on any platform, but as they could be written in native code, it is technically feasible that there could be a bug preventing one of them running on a certain platform.

Using JNI (Java Native Interface) there can be some problems, but this would generally be in the C/C++ code calling and being called from Java.

Comment: OK,  so my code compiles fine with both JDKs but I have memory issues at runtime.  I get an out of memory Heap Error when running unit tests through ANT when pointing it to a 64 bit JDK but it runs fine when using a 32 bit JDK.  Would this be a typical problem you might expect to see between the two?

Comment: Well, it's not necessarily a problem that I'd expect to see, but 64bit software generally uses more memory than 32bit. So, it's perfectly feasible.

This is a general 64bit issue, and not specific to Java.

Try using the -Xmx option with the vm to increase the memory available to Java. It's memory has a fixed limit and the default is for a max of about quarter of a gig.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Compiler is not aware of the underlying hardware.

Java Source ----> Java Compiler ------> **Bytecode (Hardware Independent)**

Bytecode -------> Java Runtime  --------> **Machine Level Code (Platform/Hardware dependent)**

So its not possible for Java code that runs on one hardware to not work on other.

The answer to your second question is that for creating the machine level code for the bytecode the **Runtime** has to know what operations are supported by the underlying hardware.

Instructions for 32 and 64 bit machines are different.